# DotnetCore PostAddFile returns 504 after a while of usage

Tags: docker, nginx, .net-core, umbraco

I have a strange error. I have deployed Umbraco 11.3.1 to a Linux server with Dokku and Docker. It runs .NET Core. I have set up a volume of the `/umbraco/Data` and the `/media` directories. In the beginning, it works as planned - I can upload files to the media dir and I can see the output in the volume dir outside Docker. But after hours of usage, the `/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/media/PostAddFile` endpoint fails with a 504. The upload bar runs as it usually do, but when it reach 100% and after a minute or so, this weird HTML error appears.

[image]

[image]

That is a Nginx error as far as I know. Blue screen.

[image]

In my nginx error log, I see this:

```
  2023/05/18 11:53:48 [error] 8165#8165: *30932 upstream timed out (110: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.165.xxx.xxx, server: mydomain.dk, request: "POST /umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/media/PostAddFile HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:4000/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/media/PostAddFile", host: "mydomain.dk", referrer: "https://mydomain.dk/umbraco"
```

If I rebuild the Docker container and works again for a while.

I can't figure out if this is a docker, Umbraco, or an nginx error. Please help me in the right direction, or where/how to debug :)

/Peter

Comment: did you ever see a solution to this? We have just started seeing this issue. After a few days of running the dotnet process, Umbraco does not give a response on the upload request. In our case we have a production server with nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Umbraco running its built in Kestrel. No output from Umbraco, and nginx hits its proxy timeout basically after 90 seconds.

Comment: I had a post here as well: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/111879-postaddfile-returns-504-after-a-while - After I updated to 11.4 the problem seems to disappear for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer on Umbraco forum:

https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/111879-postaddfile-returns-504-after-a-while

It seems to be fixed with 11.4 :)